# Allow only attached Auth users [ Course owners ] to access course view page [LARAVEL Policies ]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to restrict Auth users access to only courses they are attached to

I tried the following but still not working properly

1- Created a new Policy called CoursePolicy with the following function

```
public function show(User $user, Course $course)
    {
         return $user->id === $course->user_id;
    }
```

2- Binded the policy to the Course Model like so in the AuthServiceProvide.php :

```
protected $policies = [
    Course::class => CoursePolicy::class,
];
```

3- In my CoursesController  Controller .. used authorizeForUser

```
public function show(Course $course)
    {

        $this->authorizeForUser(Auth::user(), 'show', [$course]);

    return $this->makeResponse('courses.show', compact('course'));
      
    }
```

Course.php

```
  public function users(){return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();}
```

User.php

```
    public function courses() {return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();}
```

End Result ::

me [ as an auth user ] .. blocked from all courses views .. even the one that I'm attached to ...

What am I missing here :(

Comment: why would Course have a `user_id` field if there is a pivot that relates it to User?

Comment: you are right .. I don't have user_id field in courses table  .. then Ok bro how can I correct that ?